# Multivariable Calculus distance word problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Four towns wish to build a radio station. Suppose that the towns are located at (0, 0), (7,0), (0, 3) and (3, 3) on a square grid.

At what point (a, b) should the station be located to minimize the sum of the squares of the distances from each town to the station?

Is there an equation I should be plugging this into? I'm not sure what method I should be using to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's build it at $(a,b)$. Then the sum of the squares of the distances is

$$\left(a^2+b^2\right)+\left((a-7)^2+b^2\right)+\left(a^2+(b-3)^2\right)+\left((a-3)^2+(b-3)^2\right)$$

which is

$$4a^2+4b^2-20a-12b+76$$

or, another way to write it,

$$4(a-\tfrac52)^2+4(b-\tfrac32)^2+\tfrac{135}2$$

Since we cannot make squares less than zero, we can minimize this expression by setting $a$ and $b$ such that the squares are zero.
Thus, $a=\tfrac52$ and $b=\tfrac32$, so we should build the radio station at $(2.5,1.5)$.